# Script error in line 0 on a JS environment

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, runtime-error

I've got a problem with my JS code. I have to construct an alarm clock with objects, but It doesn't work, even It seems to me fine.
Here is:

```
function AlarmClock(){

  this.hour;
  this.minutes;
  this.Hours=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

  this.currentTime=
    function(h, m){
    this.hour=h;
    this.minutes=m;
    if (this.hour>23){
      this.hour=0;
    }
    if(this.minutes>59){
      this.minutes=0;
    }
  }

  this.alarm=
    function(h, m){
    this.hour=h;
    this.minutes=m;
    if(this.hour>23){
      this.hour=0;
    }
    if(this.minutes>59){
      this.minutes=0;
    }
  }

  this.tic=
    function(){
    var i=0;
    while(i<=m){
      m.currentTime+=i;
    if(m.currentTime==60){
      h.currentTime+=1;
    }
   if (h.currentTime==24){
      h.currentTime=0;
    } 
   if(((h.currentTime)&&(m.currentTime))==((h.alarm)&&(m.alarm))){
      return ("Time to wake up!");
    }else{
        i++;
    }
  }
}

function foo(){
  var c=new AlarmClock();
  c.currentTime(13, 0);
  c.alarm(13, 2);
}
  foo();
```

I've tried it twice in two different environment:

- the first JSenvironment,(http://www.di.unipi.it/~mezzetti/easyjs2/) give me a `"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"` (maybe because I had make some mistakes)
- on the other hand, the second one ( http://www.squarefree.com/jsenv/) give me this error `"Error on line 0: Script error."`

How can I ride over this?

Thank you so much :D

Comment: you need an extra `}` before `function foo(){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Function `AlarmClock()` is missing one last closing braces `}`. Just put a `}` above function `foo()`.

Comment: Thank you to everyone, I will give more attention to braces ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `}` for your `function AlarmClock(){`:

```
function AlarmClock(){

  this.hour;
  this.minutes;
  this.Hours=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

  this.currentTime=
    function(h, m){
    this.hour=h;
    this.minutes=m;
    if (this.hour>23){
      this.hour=0;
    }
    if(this.minutes>59){
      this.minutes=0;
    }
  }

  this.alarm=
    function(h, m){
    this.hour=h;
    this.minutes=m;
    if(this.hour>23){
      this.hour=0;
    }
    if(this.minutes>59){
      this.minutes=0;
    }
  }

  this.tic=
    function(){
    var i=0;
    while(i<=m){
      m.currentTime+=i;
    if(m.currentTime==60){
      h.currentTime+=1;
    }
   if (h.currentTime==24){
      h.currentTime=0;
    } 
   if(((h.currentTime)&&(m.currentTime))==((h.alarm)&&(m.alarm))){
      return ("Time to wake up!");
    }else{
        i++;
    }
  }
}
} <----------------- HERE

function foo(){
  var c=new AlarmClock();
  c.currentTime(13, 0);
  c.alarm(13, 2);
}

foo();
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgcm32n1/)